# Trying to include c++ library, but "fatal error: xtensor/xarray.hpp: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, gcc, xtensor

I'm a c++ beginner, I have a small amount of experience using python and numpy and wanted a matrix library that resembled it that I could use in c++ and I thought I'd try xtensor. I'm using ubuntu 20, and followed the install instructions on the [github](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor) to install using the conda package (so `conda install -c conda-forge xtensor`). I created a file containing the very first example on the github, the basic usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"

xt::xarray<double> arr1
  {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
   {2.0, 5.0, 7.0},
   {2.0, 5.0, 7.0}};

xt::xarray<double> arr2
  {5.0, 6.0, 7.0};

xt::xarray<double> res = xt::view(arr1, 1) + arr2;

std::cout << res;
```

I navigate to the directory containing the file and run "g++ --verbose -o testXtensor testXtensor.cpp", but it immediately fails and the terminal returns:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-Av3uEd/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'testXtensor' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE testXtensor.cpp -quiet -dumpbase testXtensor.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase testXtensor -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/ccqFVVyC.s
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) version 9.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/9
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9
 /usr/include/c++/9/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) version 9.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 65fe925b83d3956b533de4aaba7dace0
testXtensor.cpp:2:10: fatal error: xtensor/xarray.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What have I done wrong? To the extent I understand the report in the terminal it seems g++ doesn't know where the xtensor library is and consequently I have nothing in my `#include "..." search starts here:` section, but I'm really not sure how to tell it how to find it and I'm confused why the instructions for this aren't included in the install instructions if this is something you need to do manually every time? My g++ version is 9.4.0 and conda is 4.14.0, if that matters. Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: Where are the xtensor header installed? What is the full absolute path to e.g. `xtensor/xarray.hpp`?

Comment: Hi, the full path is: /home/matt/miniconda3/pkgs/xtensor-0.23.10-h4bd325d_0/include/xtensor/xarray.hpp

Comment: Then when building, try adding the option `-I/home/matt/miniconda3/pkgs/xtensor-0.23.10-h4bd325d_0/include` option (and `-I` is with the upper-case i).

Comment: So in my terminal, ```g++ -o testXtensor testXtensor.cpp -I/home/matt/miniconda3/pkgs/xtensor-0.23.10-h4bd325d_0/include```? 

That returns:

```In file included from testXtensor.cpp:2:
/home/matt/miniconda3/pkgs/xtensor-0.23.10-h4bd325d_0/include/xtensor/xarray.hpp:17:10: fatal error: xtl/xsequence.hpp: No such file or directory
   17 | #include <xtl/xsequence.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```
xtl/xsequence.hpp is included via xarray.hpp, xtl appears to be in the same ```miniconda3/pkgs``` folder

Comment: The [documentation](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#compiling-the-first-example) tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've managed to get it working now. I was following the instructions on the github page rather than the readthedocs page, which doesn't have the section about needing to link to the locations when compiling. In answer to your pre-edit post, I figured that the business of pointing to where libraries were was therefore somehow handled behind the scenes in the install (again, I am a beginner!).